# Grails: Two Sites, One Codebase

Tags: grails

I have a sizable Grails application that has a small handful of controllers and views, and a very large number of Services.

I now need to build a "reskinned" version of the same site which has its own set of views and controllers (there are some smallish differences in how the controllers work), but the exact same set of Services.  One option is to move all of the services into some kind of common place via custom Grails plugins, but I'm wondering if there's another way.

What I'd like to do is have two packages in the controllers folder, com.company.sitea and com.company.siteb, with an environment variable that effectively chooses which one of those is used.  Similarly, two different sets of views, each one selected based on this environment variable, but with a shared taglib.

I was unable to find anything obvious that did this, is there a plugin or a standard way of doing this (or something similar)?  The idea is, I'd have one codebase, I'd build one war, but the war would be deployed in two different places, and each one of those would specify a value for a special environment variable.

Comment: Honestly, I'd go the plugin route myself.  Or even pull the services out into their own grails app (WAR) and have the controllers talk to them as webservices.

Comment: Yeah, this is what we'll do if we can't keep them all together, but in my experience splitting up a codebase semi-needlessly discourages refactoring and causes lock-step-change nightmares that I detest.  These two sites will share about 98% of the functionality (excluding view-specifics), it'd be a shame to turn one codebase into three for it.

Comment: I also vote for the "common" plugin route. since you are already making a plugin anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have been successfully using a pattern where we make the first application a plugin. It will be run as an application for the first use case and included as a plugin to the second use case.

If you do this (a grails application is a application and plugin at the same time), you have to exclude the plugin from starting up when it's run as an application. Otherwise the application will start it self twice: as an application and as a plugin. The "grails.plugin.excludes" configuration setting (explained here) prevents this from happening.

I have documented this special use case in this jira issue:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6751 
"Allow a Grails application to be used as a Grails plugin besides using it as an application"

This has turned out to be a killer feature for us in many cases. We have been able to reuse applications as plugins in other use cases and combine several separate applications to one with this feature. Of course there are some restrictions (like name conflicts) but that hasn't been a problem for us.

The most common use case is to reuse a full application and just override the views in another one. Since an existing application can be an application and plugin at the same time, there is no extra work in extracting "common parts" to a separate plugin.

To make an existing Grails application a plugin you just have to add a MyAppNameGrailsPlugin.groovy file to the root directory and add this configuration value to grails-app/conf/Config.groovy: 
grails.plugin.excludes = ['myAppName'] (application name in camel case starting with lower case letter)

Mailing list discussion:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Dynamic-applications-extending-an-existing-application-with-Grails-tp4634094p4634202.html

Burt's detailed blog post:
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1973

David Dawson's presentation:
http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/large-scale-grails-using-plugins-how-to-modularise-an-application/jd-8012

Answer (score 0):

one important factor is whether both of these versions should operate on the same data? so they will be different front-ends over same database? or they will be completely separate, for example per-customer deployment?

if the first, I would go webservices way, so one app would contain business logic, and controllers working as webservices, and other app would just have different controller, "talking" to the first one

you could also combine everything in one project (both versions) and limit access to different controllers from different domains with apache unmounts

if the latter, I would also try to extract common part into a plugin

Comment: Neither of these versions connect to any databases, they do everything via web services (that's why they share so many Service classes)